# Solve equation in python

Tags: python

I am new to python (24 hours old).

I am trying to create a program in python that can help me solve equations.

For example: To calculate profit, the general, and a very simple equation for a manufacturing unit should be:

Labor-hour-rate*(hours_worked) + No_of_units_produced*raw_material_cost = Total cost.

**Now, in this equation there 5 variables. I want to create a program where I input 4 of the 5 variables, the 5th variable should be calculated.**

For e.g., If I input

1. Labour-hour-rate = 20
2. hours_worked = 2
3. No_of_units_produced = 10
4. Total Cost = 80

then, the program should calculate, raw_material_cost = 4

I know one way is to create a separate function for each parameter, but I think there must be a smarter way to do it in Python

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks
Himanshu

Comment: See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve using `namedtuple`. And what you want to find set is as `None`.

```py
import collections
def calculate(args):
    if args.total_cost is None:
        total_cost = (args.labour_hour_rate * args.hours_worked) + (args.no_of_units_produced * args.raw_material_cost)
        print("total_cost =", total_cost)
    elif args.hours_worked is None:
        hours_worked = (args.total_cost - args.no_of_units_produced * args.raw_material_cost) / args.labour_hour_rate
        print("hours_worked =", hours_worked)
    elif args.labour_hour_rate is None:
        labour_hour_rate = (args.total_cost - args.no_of_units_produced * args.raw_material_cost) / args.hours_worked
        print("labour_hour_rate =", labour_hour_rate)
    elif args.no_of_units_produced is None:
        no_of_units_produced = (args.total_cost - args.labour_hour_rate * args.hours_worked) / args.raw_material_cost
        print("no_of_units_produced =", no_of_units_produced)
    elif args.raw_material_cost is None:
        raw_material_cost = (args.total_cost - args.labour_hour_rate * args.hours_worked) / args.no_of_units_produced
        print("raw_material_cost =", raw_material_cost)

Variables = collections.namedtuple("Equation", "labour_hour_rate hours_worked  no_of_units_produced total_cost raw_material_cost")
calculate(Variables(20, 2, 10, 80, None))
calculate(Variables(20, 2, 10, None, 4))
calculate(Variables(20, 2, None, 80, 4))
calculate(Variables(20, None, 10, 80, 4))
calculate(Variables(None, 2, 10, 80, 4))
```

**Output:**

```
raw_material_cost = 4.0
total_cost = 80
no_of_units_produced = 10.0
hours_worked = 2.0
labour_hour_rate = 20.0
```